# Studying Torah with a Gentile

Tags: gentiles, torah-study

There is a non Jewish intellectual with whom I would like to study Torah. I have Biblical Hebrew skills and he has age, experience, and knowledge that would be mutually beneficial. May I learn Torah together with him?

Answer (score 0):

In general, teaching Non-Jews Torah is discouraged, but there are some exceptions.
Any Torah learning related to the seven Noachide laws is allowed, and even a Mitzvah (see Tosafos Chagiga), and many Sifrei Mussar may be included in this also, since they teach these universal themes.
Additionally, many authorities permit teaching Tanach to non-Jews (Netziv and Maharitz Chayos among others).
It seems like you want to learn Tanach with him (since you talk about biblical hebrew skills), so it's probarly okay.